# Increase only dropdown item width

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looking to increase only the dropdown item width . I found two samples

1. http://css-tricks.com/select-cuts-off-options-in-ie-fix/
2. http://jsbin.com/acado/6

But the first one increases the width of dropdown, not the item, in IE7

Is there any other option available

Answer (score 0):

```
<style type="text/css">
  select {width: 100px;}
  option {width: 500px;}
</style>
```

Comment: Works well in FF, but not in IE7 'code' <html lang="en">
   'code'
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>MSIE dropdown auto-width</title>
        
        <style type="text/css">
  select {width: 100px;}
  option {width: 400px;}
</style>  
    </head>
    <body>
       
        <select class="ProductAttributesSelect" id="dropdown">
            <option>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</option>
            <option>consectetur adipiscing elit</option>
            <option>Curabitur ut nisi neque</option>
        </select>
       
    </body>
</html>